# Problema a la hora de redireccionar carácteres especiales con Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

Estoy realizando una página web con *Spring MV*C y diversas `.jsp`.
Los `jsp` están formados por diferentes enlaces que al pulsarlo llamarán a un controlador de *Spring MVC*. Pues tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo un enlace en el `jsp` llamado así:

```
<a class="btn btn-link" href='/Practica_Prueba/infoContenido1/Diseño'> Diseño </a>
```

El controlador es el siguiente:

```
@RequestMapping("/infoContenido1/{cont}")
public String calculoContenido(ModelMap model, @PathVariable("cont") String cont, HttpSession session) {
    cont = cont + "Info";
    return "redirect:/infoContenidoVirtual/"+cont;
}
```

En este controlador lo único que hago es añadirle la palabra *Info* a *Diseño* y le puse un syso para visualizar como quedaba `cont` y era "*DiseñoInfo*", por lo que hasta aquí todo correcto. Este controlador redirecciona a otro que recibe la variable cont así

```
@RequestMapping("/infoContenidoVirtual/{cont}")
```

Y dentro del controlador he puesto un *syso* y lo que recibe es "*Dise%F1oInfo*". Por lo que sea al redireccionar cambia la `ñ` por `%F1`.

He probado a poner todo en el mismo controlador y funciona bien, el problema es que necesito obligatoriamente llamar a otro controlador (*redirect*) y esto produce que se cambie la `ñ` por `%F1`. Esto también ocurre si una palabra tiene un acento (`á`,`é`,etc).

¿Cómo se podría solucionar el problema?

Comment: por que no limpias eso antes de mandarlo al controlador y en el controlador pones Diseno

Comment: Puedes intentar poniendo `\u00f1` en lugar de `ñ`, o cambia `diseño` por `disenio` en tu redirect, en tu HTML coloca   &#241; en lugar de `ñ`  ya que puedes tener problemas de visualización entre versiones de navegadores.

Comment: Pero el problema es que no es solo la ñ, también hay otras palabras con tildes y otros caracteres con los que ocurre lo mismo.

Comment: Todo lo que viaje en la URL lo va a escapar para que tenga formato de URL. TOca des-escaparlo (url decode) o te toca usar ascii en los parámetros pa que no escape nada :)

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver este problema debes decodificar el URI antes de utilizarlo. El navegador codifica estilo UR utilizando UTF-8 por defecto. Para decodificar tu URI utilizando codificación UTF-8 debes hacer algo similar a esto:

```
@RequestMapping("/infoContenido1/{cont}")
public String calculoContenido(ModelMap model, @PathVariable("cont") String cont, HttpSession session) {
    cont = URLDecoder.decode(cont, "UTF-8") + "Info";
    return "redirect:/infoContenidoVirtual/"+cont;
}
```

Referencias:

[URLDecoder#decode(String s,
            String enc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))